# Ethereum hangs after 3 days uploading the blockchain, do I even need the blockchain to have a wallet?

Tags: mist, wallets

I have downloaded and run Ethereum Wallet 0.9.0 Mist. It started updating about 3 days ago. It runs, but then when it is very near the end, e.g. 300-ish blocks to go, it seems to slow down and stop. I tried rebooting my computer and it did the same thing: download a lot of blocks but get stuck at the end. I was about 95% complete. Then today, I rebooted again and started up the Ethereum Wallet again. Now it says I am 80% complete.
Is there a problem with the software?

All I want to do is move my Ethereum off my Jaxx wallet to the official wallet. With Jaxx apparently I can't import a paper Ether wallet. Am I even using the right software? I really don't care about the entire blockchain and actually would prefer not to have it take up all that room on my HD.

Also, in the Ethereum Wallet, I can't for the life of me find the private key. Where is it?

Sorry for these newbie questions, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be happening a lot for different people at the moment: See https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15001, https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14988, https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14995 and https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2985... try running `geth` in `--fast` mode followed by normal mode and ensure you are on a SSD drive. You will probably need to run it overnight a few times to catch up. Seems the Mist client is not accepting transactions unless you have caught up 100%.

Comment: Sorry, don't have an ssd. I have a 5GB conventional disk drive. And I'm on a rather old iMac. :( Am I out of luck on this?

Comment: Its definitely possible to catch up to the latest ETH blocks - I managed to do it with a 2012-era MacBook (100Gb storage atm) - just keep the software running and avoid restarting it. Fast mode is for the initial download of the bulk of the blockchain (as it skips normal validation checks for every block). The Mist client is used to load up the JSON files you got in the initial Ether release, but you will need your original password to get the transaction to succeed.

Comment: https://daowiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DAO/pages/7962732/How+to+run+fast+sync+on+Mist+using+geth

Comment: Also try `light` mode from scratch without any blocks downloaded initially - https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6lzw8y/how_to_run_ethereum_wallet_in_light_mode/

Answer (score -1):

I just found a chrome extension for myetherwallet
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/myetherwallet/nlbmnnijcnlegkjjpcfjclmcfggfefdm/related?hl=en

Answer (score -2):

In that case you can use myetherwallet.com.
You'll get your private Keys and you don't have to download the blockchain.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Maybe I am confused, but I already looked at myetherwallet.com. I used that to create a paper wallet. That's from where I cannot re-send to Jaxx. There must be a link on myetherwallet.com to download their desktop and mobile wallets?

Comment: @JoeM yes, if you check their GitHub, you can have their "wallet" software completely offline. https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet . Look at your Jaxx wallet and get the private key from that wallet. Type this into myetherwallet, and now you can use their wallet software to send tx's